# remove duplicate links from a file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, duplicates

I have a big file with links something like this:

```
http://aaaa1.com/weblink/link1.html#XXX
http://aaaa1.com/weblink/link1.html#XYZ
http://aaaa1.com/weblink/link2.html#XXX
http://bbbb.com/web1/index.php?index=1
http://bbbb.com/web1/index1.php?index=1
http://bbbb.com/web1/index1.php?index=2
http://bbbb.com/web1/index1.php?index=3
http://bbbb.com/web1/index1.php?index=4
http://bbbb.com/web1/index1.php?index=5
http://bbbb.com/web1/index2.php?index=666
http://bbbb.com/web1/index3.php?index=666
http://bbbb.com/web1/index4.php?index=5
```

I want to remove all duplicate links and remain with:

```
http://aaaa1.com/weblink/link1.html#XXX
http://aaaa1.com/weblink/link2.html#XXX
http://bbbb.com/web1/index.php?index=1
http://bbbb.com/web1/index1.php?index=1
http://bbbb.com/web1/index2.php?index=666
http://bbbb.com/web1/index3.php?index=666
http://bbbb.com/web1/index4.php?index=5
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have showed good sample input and sample expected output in code tags keep it up. On SO we always encourage all OPs to post their effort also in your post too.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Some [mcve] would be usefull. One point further, unless taking aside querystring or hashstring, I can't see any actual duplicate here. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[#?]' '!a[$1]++'  Input_file
```

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk -F'[#?]' '    ##Starting awk script from here and making field separator as #(hash) and ?(literal character) as per OP sample Input_file provided.
!a[$1]++          ##Creating an array whose index is $1(first field of current line). Checking condition if $1 is NOT present in a then increase its value with 1.
                  ##And ! condition will make sure each lines $1 should come only 1 time in array a so by doing this all duplicates will NOT be printed.
' Input_file      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will clear all the duplicate links from your file but there should be exactly similar values.

```
sort -u your-link-file.txt
```

And if you want to store it to another file then use this

```
cat your-link-file.txt | sort -u > result.txt
```